Guardar imagen con expo picker image y mostrarla en la siguiente pantallla sin subirla a servidor
Hola estoy interesado en que el usuario seleccione una imagen de su galeria con expo picker image para que despues se muestre una vista previa de esta imagen mas adelante, pero al pasarle el uri almacenado a la siguiente pantalla segun entiendo 'expira' por lo que es temporal, quiero econtrar la manera de pasarle la imagen sin tener que subirla a un servidor o algo por el estilo.
Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const pickImage  = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      Alert.alert("Error", "Necesitas permisos para acceder a la galería");
      return;
    }
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
      allowsEditing: true,
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      const { uri, type } = result.assets[0];
      const imageType = type ?? "image/jpeg"; 
      const fileName = `image_${Date.now()}`; 
      setPreview(uri);
    }
  };

  const setPreview = (uri: string) => {
    setSelectedImage(uri);
  };

Despues en el siguiente componente intento mostrar el uri de la imagen y se muestra correctamente asi :
<Text style={styles.textbold}>uri de la imagen {selectedImage}</Text>

Pero al poner el uri desde  no se muestra la imagen a pesar que de que no esta vacia
Intente guardarlas en async storage pero no lo he conseguido alguien puede echarme una mano?
